# The strange Node.js error after starting script

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I use **Node.js**.
My server js script I run such:

> node chat_server.js

After I get errors messages in terminal **CentOS**:

> Express server listening on port undefined in development mode.

*+ User undefined connected node_redis: no callback to send error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'sadd' command*

> /home/who/public_html/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:582
>               throw err;
>                     ^ Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'sadd' command
>       at ReplyParser. (/home/who/public_html/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:317:31)
>       at ReplyParser.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at ReplyParser.send_error (/home/who/public_html/node/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:296:10)
>       at ReplyParser.execute (/home/who/public_html/node/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:181:22)
>       at RedisClient.on_data (/home/who/public_html/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:547:27)
>       at Socket. (/home/who/public_html/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:102:14)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Socket. (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
>
> at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)

Excuse me, but I do not understand the reason of these errors. 
On what I should get attention and how fix it?

For example, I use command **redis SADD**: `redis_cli.sadd( "user.friend:" + currentIdUser, data.idUser);`

I **have done a experiment**, created a new text script:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.sadd("users","naveen",function(err,reply){
    console.log('Ok');
        if(err)
            throw err;
        return reply;

   });
```

It have given me in console: OK. It mean, that all works fine.
I think in my code:

```
redis_cli.sadd("userslist", currentIdUser);
```

the variable **currentUser** is simply empty or undefined. It gives me the next errors.

Comment: check your port variable...

Comment: Redis is available now, via client console: **# redis_cli** Port is: **6379** in /redis/index.js                                `default_port = 6379,
    default_host = "127.0.0.1";`

Comment: `redis` and `node` version?

Comment: Here is a same problem: https://github.com/malditogeek/vmux/issues/20                             **Node Version** v0.10.29,  **Redis Version** v=2.8.12 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=630f2ccf4a71c8e5

Comment: All versions are not old. Only can try to update Redis. But dont know how at CentOS. I installed redis via NPM: **npm install redis** Maybe in this problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem was at my script in line:

```
redis_cli.sadd("userslist", currentIdUser);
```

The variable is **undefined**. It calls error redis.
Thank you all for help.